# Matplotlib - ValueError: Illegal argument(s) to subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 4 figures (y1,y2,y3,y4) that i want to plot on a common x axis (yr1,yr2,yr3,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5). In this code however i have kept axaxis as separate since i am trying to get the basics right first.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
xaxis = ['y1','y2','y3','m1','m2','m3', 'm4', 'm5']
y1 = np.array([.73,.74,.71,.75,.72,.75,.74,.74])
y2 = np.array([.82,.80,.77,.81,.72,.81,.77,.77])
y3 = np.array([.35,.36,.45,.43,.44,.45,.48,.45])
y4 = np.array([.49,.52,.59,.58,.61,.65,.61,.58])

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(xaxis,y1)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(xaxis,y2)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.subplot(xaxis,y3)
plt.subplot(224)
plt.subplot(xaxis,y4)
plt.show()
```

Getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-dfe04cc8c6c4> in <module>
     14 plt.plot(xaxis,y2)
     15 plt.subplot(223)
---> 16 plt.subplot(xaxis,y3)
     17 plt.subplot(224)
     18 plt.subplot(xaxis,y4)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1074 
   1075     fig = gcf()
-> 1076     a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1077     bbox = a.bbox
   1078     byebye = []

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1412                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
   1413 
-> 1414             a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1415 
   1416         return self._add_axes_internal(key, a)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     62                 # num - 1 for converting from MATLAB to python indexing
     63         else:
---> 64             raise ValueError(f'Illegal argument(s) to subplot: {args}')
     65 
     66         self.update_params()

ValueError: Illegal argument(s) to subplot: (['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'], array([0.35, 0.36, 0.45, 0.43, 0.44, 0.45, 0.48, 0.45]))
```

Please help understand the issue here !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small mistake. You have put `plt.subplot` instead of `plt.plot`. This should work now:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
xaxis = ['y1','y2','y3','m1','m2','m3', 'm4', 'm5']
y1 = np.array([.73,.74,.71,.75,.72,.75,.74,.74])
y2 = np.array([.82,.80,.77,.81,.72,.81,.77,.77])
y3 = np.array([.35,.36,.45,.43,.44,.45,.48,.45])
y4 = np.array([.49,.52,.59,.58,.61,.65,.61,.58])

plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(xaxis,y1)
plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(xaxis,y2)
plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(xaxis,y3)
plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(xaxis,y4)
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

Reusing Sahith Kurapati's code just to provide a cleaner solution. This way you can share axes and only configure line and chart styles once if they're all supposed to have the same style.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(1)
xaxis = ['y1','y2','y3','m1','m2','m3', 'm4', 'm5']
yy = np.array([[.73,.74,.71,.75,.72,.75,.74,.74],
              [.82,.80,.77,.81,.72,.81,.77,.77],
              [.35,.36,.45,.43,.44,.45,.48,.45],
              [.49,.52,.59,.58,.61,.65,.61,.58]])

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
for y, ax in zip(yy, axes.ravel()):
    ax.plot(y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(4, 1,sharex=True,gridspec_kw= {'height_ratios':[3,1,1,1]})
ax[0].plot(xais,y1)
ax[1].plot(xais,y1)
ax[2].plot(xais,y1)
ax[3].plot(xais,y1)
```

for 4 figures stacked on top of each other with shared x-axis.

for 2x2:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0].plot(xaxis,y1)
ax[0,1].plot(xaxis,y1)
ax[1,0].plot(xaxis,y1)
ax[1,1].plot(xaxis,y1)
```

and then plt.show() to see results.

Look here for more:
[For more here is an example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/spectrum_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-spectrum-demo-py)

Comment: Thanks a ton @user3850153 ! what are fig and ax. Looks like ax represent different graphs on the 2 x 2 plot for e.g. used ax[0,0].set_title('Fig 1') but what is "fig". 

How do we use it

Comment: fig represents your whole figure. If you have another fig (running this command again) two windows will open. ax is an array of plots inside the figure. It could also be used like this:
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplot(2, 2)

https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html#matplotlib.pyplot.figure 
https://matplotlib.org/3.2.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes

Comment: Thanks, This clarifies